# Jquery Load ID required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I do is create a new table cell, then I want to place the image content from this website into that table cell, however the table cell doesn't have an ID, with load am i required to do

```
$("#id").load("http://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com li:first img");
```

or can I do something like this, because I can't give seperate ID's to everyone.

```
var tdPic = document.createElement("td");
tdPic.innerHTML = load("http://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com li:first img");
```

Comment: Is that your domain? If not you're probably going to fall foul of the Same Origin Policy before you even get an image to append.

Comment: Why not simply `tdPic = $('<td>'); tdPic.load...` ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hmm, so is there a way around this? I just simply want to get an image from the website.

Comment: @dystroy When I set tdPic to that, does that create an element with an id? or just create a td element?

Comment: @Jupiter There's not really a way around this. You can't read the html code of another site unless it explicitly allows it, for security resons.

Comment: It doesn't set an ID but I thought you didn't need it. For now, if you don't have the direct url of the image (or its position and size), you have a more pressing problem, as pointed by Rory.

Comment: @dystroy I mean, I can access the url of the image within that img tag. And no i do not need the ID tag, so that code will do ty.

Comment: if you are only looking for one image why can't you simply get the url for image and create an image tag locally and insert that image tag as html in `TD`? Alternatively you coud use YQL to scrape remote page and return the image details in JSONP format

Comment: @charlietfl what I have is someone enters an item name, it then goes to the search page on the website of that item and grabs the image, so i can't just enter the image it is all dependent on what the user enters. Ok, I will look into YQL then.

Comment: $("#id").html('<img src="http://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com li:first img"');

Comment: @DavidFregoli wow, ok ty lets hope this works

Comment: ehm no I meant just the url sorry :D